# Does someone tried the PowerShell command "add-OdbcDsn" with success when using MariaDB Connector Driver?

Tags: powershell, odbc

I tried the example from the official documentation of Microsoft:

```
$DsnArray = Get-OdbcDsn -DriverName 'MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver'
ForEach ($Dsn in $DsnArray) {
    Remove-OdbcDsn -InputObject $Dsn
    Add-OdbcDsn -Name $Dsn.Name -DsnType "User" -DriverName 'MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver' `
               -SetPropertyValue $Dsn.PropertyValue
}
```

This script reads entries, remove them, and add them without changing any of the parameters.
It did not work and print "error 11".

Answer (score 0):

From tech-net forums: `Error 11 = "missing required parameter"`

When tested I found out `SetPropertyValue` cannot take in empty attributes:

> Syntax error in the parameter SetPropertyValue {lockWaitTimeout=}. It
> must be in the format
> | "MyKey=MyValue".

Looks like you'd have to sanitize (filter out) or provide values for empty property values.